# pandas: grouping and selecting one row based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a pandas sequence of functions that given input like this:

```
 id   label    rank
aab   quz         2
aaa   foo         1
aac   bar         4
aad   foo         4
aac   foo         2
aac   baz         3
aab   baz         3
aaa   bar         5
```

groups by `id` and within each group selects the record with the lowest `rank`.  The output would look like the following:

Output:

```
id   label    rank
aaa  foo         1
aab  qaz         3
aac  foo         2
aad  foo         4
```

Assuming unordered input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest would probably be to sort by rank, group by id and pick the first element per group;

```
> df.sort('rank').groupby('id').first().reset_index()

#     id label  rank
# 0  aaa   foo     1
# 1  aab   quz     2
# 2  aac   foo     2
# 3  aad   foo     4
```

Comment: Does pandas guarantee that grouped rows will keep the initial sort order within each group?

Comment: @DmitryB. I read it that way; [*groupby preserves the order of rows within each group*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by column `id`, apply function [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for finding indexes of rows with minimal values of column `rank`. Then use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for selecting those rows:

```
print df.groupby('id')['rank'].idxmin()
id
aaa    1
aab    0
aac    4
aad    3
Name: rank, dtype: int64

print df.loc[df.groupby('id')['rank'].idxmin(),:]
    id label  rank
1  aaa   foo     1
0  aab   quz     2
4  aac   foo     2
3  aad   foo     4
```

Or:

```
print df.loc[df.groupby('id')['rank'].idxmin()]
    id label  rank
1  aaa   foo     1
0  aab   quz     2
4  aac   foo     2
3  aad   foo     4
```

**Timing**:

`len(df) = 8`:

```
In [153]: %timeit df.sort_values('rank').groupby('id').first().reset_index()
The slowest run took 4.30 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.26 ms per loop

In [154]: %timeit df.loc[df.groupby('id')['rank'].idxmin(),:]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.67 ms per loop

In [155]: %timeit df.loc[df.groupby('id')['rank'].idxmin()]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.52 ms per loop
```

`len(df) = 8k`:

```
In [157]: %timeit df.sort_values('rank').groupby('id').first().reset_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 3.55 ms per loop

In [158]: %timeit df.loc[df.groupby('id')['rank'].idxmin(),:]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.24 ms per loop

In [159]: %timeit df.loc[df.groupby('id')['rank'].idxmin()]
The slowest run took 4.35 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.12 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I ultimately went with the other answer because that's what I ended up using in my code.

Comment: No problem. If you look to [cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#new-columns), your question has two possible solutions. Happy coding. :) Btw, better is use `sort_values` as `sort`, because `warning`